# Looking for a collaborator in tree-automata, tree-grammars field

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It can be very useful feature for science-oriented stackexchange forum to have a separate sub-site to post there advertisements about project collaboration.

In particular, I have a big issue with finding a collaborator. I am doing some side-research project in the `tree-automata` and `tree-grammars` field. I am looking for a collaborator to do this research together. 
I have no idea where to post such kind of advertisement.

Comment: Cool idea!  I'm quite interested in decision problems related to tree automata.  :)

Comment: https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2963/community-promotion-ads-2017